# How to merge 2 separate query and group by specific field with group_concat

Tags: mysql, group-by, concatenation, multiple-select

I have used UNION for 2 separate Mysql query, The query is as below.

```
select country,u_id from
(SELECT  regionShortName as country , GROUP_CONCAT( urls_regions.u_id ) AS      
u_id
FROM urls_regions
where LENGTH(regionShortName )<=2
GROUP by regionShortName)

UNION

(SELECT  countries.name as country,
        GROUP_CONCAT( urls_regions.u_id ) AS u_id
FROM `countries` countries
inner join regions on countries.regions_id = regions.id
INNER JOIN urls_regions ON regions.region = urls_regions.regionShortName
GROUP by countries.name, country)
```

The above query has given me the results as below,

[image]

I am not able to achieve as below,

Now I would like know how to group by the **"country"** by concat(merge or join) **"u_id"**

Is my query implemented is right approach or is there any other approach to achieve this.

Comment: perform group_conact lastly.

Comment: Thans for your suggestion, I tried group_concat but get mysql error right syntax error #1064

Comment: Why don't you try join and then distinct on the selected fields.

Comment: Can you make SQLFiddle or sample output which do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using below query I am able to get what I am expecting,

```
select tb.country, GROUP_CONCAT(tb.u_id, ',') from
((SELECT  regionShortName as country , GROUP_CONCAT( urls_regions.u_id ) AS      
u_id
FROM urls_regions
where LENGTH(regionShortName )<=2
GROUP by regionShortName) 
union
(SELECT  countries.name as country,
 GROUP_CONCAT(urls_regions.u_id ) AS u_id
FROM `countries` countries
inner join regions on countries.regions_id = regions.id
INNER JOIN urls_regions ON regions.region = urls_regions.regionShortName
GROUP by countries.name, country)) tb group by tb.country
```

I have done 2 things
In my first line of query I have added **GROUP_CONCAT(tb.u_id, ',')**

In the last line added **group by tb.country**